# How to convert MultipartFile into byte stream

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

//Or any other solution to saving multipartfile into DB.
I tried with this way but getting error.

```
File fileOne = new File("file.getOrignalFileName");//what should be kept inside this method 
byte[] bFile = new byte[(int) fileOne.length()];
try {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileOne);
    //convert file into array of bytes
    fileInputStream.read(bFile);
    fileInputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
questionDao.saveImage(bFile);
```

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: What error are you getting?  How is it saved in the DB (do use ORM mapping?)  Which kind of Multipart file are using (MIME, JMS, ..)?

Comment: I am trying to take Image file(png) using ORM mapping will it work

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
MultipartFile  file;
byte [] byteArr=file.getBytes();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArr);
```

Comment: Hi @sanjaya when i try to get bytes, it is throwing error: _org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [receiveFailedMDN] in context with path [/IHEProfilesServices] threw exception [Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.readFully(Ljava/io/InputStream;[B)V] with root cause
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.readFully(Ljava/io/InputStream;[B)V_

Answer (score -2):

```
    //Start Photo Upload with Adhaar No// 
    if (simpleLoanDto.getPic() != null && simpleLoanDto.getAdharNo() != null) {
        String ServerDirPath = globalVeriables.getAPath() + "\\";
        File ServerDir = new File(ServerDirPath);
        if (!ServerDir.exists()) {
            ServerDir.mkdirs();
        }
        // Giving File operation permission for LINUX//
        IOperation.setFileFolderPermission(ServerDirPath);
        MultipartFile originalPic = simpleLoanDto.getPic();
        byte[] ImageInByte = originalPic.getBytes();
        FileOutputStream fosFor = new FileOutputStream(
                new File(ServerDirPath + "\\" + simpleLoanDto.getAdharNo() + "_"+simpleLoanDto.getApplicantName()+"_.jpg"));
        fosFor.write(ImageInByte);
        fosFor.close();
    }
    //End  Photo Upload with Adhaar No//
```